# How can I make an image take up two rows in a tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Like in this example:

[image]

When I add it to the cellView it takes it gets cut to fit. I also don't want to touch the clipsToBound property. Is there a standard way of doing this?

UITableViewController

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return 2;
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView
                 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    UITableViewCell *cellView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    
    if (!cellView) {
        
        cellView = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    // ...
    
    return cellView;
}
```

Comment: Custom cell class is your best (and really, only) route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very, very simple example of creating that layout with a custom `UITableViewCell` class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VulkanTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
- (void)setData:(UIImage *)img topString:(NSString *)sTop bottomString:(NSString *)sBot;
@end

@interface VulkanTableViewCell ()
{
    UIImageView *theImageView;
    UILabel *topLabel;
    UILabel *botLabel;
}
@end

@implementation VulkanTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit {
    theImageView = [UIImageView new];
    topLabel = [UILabel new];
    botLabel = [UILabel new];
    
    theImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    theImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    theImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    theImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    
    UIStackView *hStack = [UIStackView new];
    hStack.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
    hStack.spacing = 16;
    
    UIStackView *vStack = [UIStackView new];
    vStack.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    vStack.spacing = 0;
    
    UIView *hLine = [UIView new];
    hLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    
    [vStack addArrangedSubview:topLabel];
    [vStack addArrangedSubview:hLine];
    [vStack addArrangedSubview:botLabel];
    
    [hStack addArrangedSubview:theImageView];
    [hStack addArrangedSubview:vStack];
    
    hStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:hStack];
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.contentView layoutMarginsGuide];
    
    // this avoid inconsequential auto-layout complaints
    NSLayoutConstraint *botConstraint = [hStack.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor];
    botConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        [hStack.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor],
        [hStack.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor],
        [hStack.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor],
        botConstraint,
        
        [theImageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60.0],
        [theImageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:theImageView.heightAnchor],
        
        [hLine.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0.5],
        
        [botLabel.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:topLabel.heightAnchor],
        
    ]];

}

- (void)setData:(UIImage *)img topString:(NSString *)sTop bottomString:(NSString *)sBot {
    theImageView.image = img;
    topLabel.text = sTop;
    botLabel.text = sBot;
}

@end

@interface VulkanTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end

@interface VulkanTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation VulkanTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:VulkanTableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"vulkanCell"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    VulkanTableViewCell *cell = (VulkanTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"vulkanCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.circle.fill", indexPath.row + 1];
    NSString *strTop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Top Label for row: %ld", indexPath.row + 1];
    NSString *strBot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bottom Label for row: %ld", indexPath.row + 1];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage systemImageNamed:imgName];
    
    [cell setData:img topString:strTop bottomString:strBot];
    
    return cell;
}

@end
```

which looks like this:

[image]